# Flash embed angular directive

Tags: javascript, angular.js

I have an app that uses HTML5 video and our customer still needs to support IE8 - Gross.

Anyway, I came up with this directive in AngularJS for embedding a SWF object for when I need to fallback to Flash. It works fine so far, but I would like to see if there is anything I can do to improve it. Can anyone see a case where this would fail? I am using `Modernizr` to detect if the browser supports video (`Modernizr.video`). If it doesn't then it falls back and I load this directive.

The directive:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('flash-embed', []).directive('flashEmbed', [function()
{
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: true,
    template: ['',
     '<object data="{{src}}" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">',
        '<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />',
        '<param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />',
        '<param name="wmode" value="transparent" />',
      '</object>'
    ].join(''),
    scope: {
      width: '@',
      height: '@',
      src: '@'
    },
    compile: function(elem, attrs, transcludeFn)
    {
      return function link (scope, element, attrs)
      {
        scope.$watch('src', function(src)
        {
          element.append('<param name="movie" value="' + src + '" />');
        });
      };
    }
  };
}]);
```

Its usage:

```
<div flash-embed src="testpreso/flash/preloader.swf" width="966" height="600"></div>
```

**EDIT**
5/8/2015 update

I am having trouble using this in IE8. A client of mine needs IE8 support, booo. The error I am getting in IE8 is:

`[Object Error] description: "Invalid argument." message:     "Invalid argument." name:        "Error" number:      -2147024809`

It has to do with the object tag I believe. I found this thread that may shed some light on the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9150938/invalid-argument-in-ie-8-on-jquery-prepend-on-flash-objects

I will update if I figure this out

Comment: This looks great to me, perhaps work in a comment about which pieces in the code are there to support IE8 specifically?

Comment: @konijn, Thanks! Nothing in this particular piece of code is related to IE8. I was just stating my reason for needing to build the directive

Comment: Any reason for  `compile`  instead of the more standard `link`?

Answer (score 1):

One would hope that this code could have been replaced with newer technologies, especially given [IE8 isn’t supported by Microsoft anymore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/internet-explorer-8) and [Adobe no longer supports Flash Player after December 31, 2020](https://www.adobe.com/products/flashplayer/end-of-life.html). Additionally [“AngularJS support has officially ended as of January 2022”](https://angularjs.org/). A framework like [VueJS](https://vuejs.org) might be a good substitute for the AngularJS.

The line that adds the `param` tag with the movie source is a bit on the long side, and the fact that it is nested in a few functions doesn’t help:

> ```
> element.append('<param name="movie" value="' + src + '" />');
> ```

This could be simplified slightly using the ES6 feature [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```
element.append(`<param name="movie" value="${src}" />`);
```